# How many cases are needed to get enough power?

Tags: probability, statistics

The following Quizzes are the rough translation (with modification) of Quizzes **No.03-1-(1)** and **No.03-1-(2)** of the exam of the "2019's semi-first grade of Japan Statistical Society Certificate (JSSC)" (See the column named **【Quizzes and Official Answers】** and ref.1). The correct answers by the JSSC  are also described under each Quiz(See the column named **【Quizzes and Official Answers】** and ref.1).

However, I don't know how to get the correct answer.

> **【My question】**:
>
> - How can I reach the correct answer?
> - For both (quiz 1) and (quiz 2), It seems that the denial of the null
>     hypothesis is not an alternative hypothesis. Is this OK for the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis?

---

> **【Quizzes and Official Answers】:**
>   We consider adverse events that occur during clinical trial and post-marketing surveillance.
>
> - Let $N$ be sample size of this clinical trial.
> - Let $p$ be the probability of the incidence of adverse events of the population ($0\le p \le 1$).
> - Let  $\hat{p}$ be estimated incidence ratio of this adverse event in
>     this clinical trial ($0\le \hat{p} \le 1$). Hereinafter, the  $\hat{p}$  are referred to as the estimated incidence ratio.
>
> We also assume that the $N$ is large enough therefore, the $\hat{p}$ on this adverse approximately follows a normal distribution.
>
> Then, Answer the following Quiz 1 and Quiz 2.
>
> **(Quiz1)** 
>   A one-sided test is performed on this **clinical trial** under the following  condition.
>
> - Let be $N= 475$ cases,
> - Let the null hypothesis ${H}_{0}$ be "$p = 0.05$" and,
> - Let the alternative hypothesis ${H}_{1}$ be "$ p> 0.05$."
>     and,
>
> We denote $P(\ \hat{p}>q |N,p)$ as the probability of the $\hat{p}>q$　under the null hypothesis.
>
> Then, **calculate the $P(\ \hat{p}>0.0733\ |N,p)$ and select best answer from the following choices**.
>
> > ① 0.01, ② 0.025, ③ 0.05, ④ 0.1, ⑤ 0.2
> >     **→Ans1: ① (0.01)**
>
> **(Quiz2)** We are planning to perform a one-sided test with a significance level of $2.5\%$  for the post-marketing surveillance under the following ${H}_{0}$, and ${H}_{1}$.
>
> - The null hypothesis ${H}_{0}$: $p = 0.05$" and,
> - The alternative hypothesis ${H}_{1}$: $p = 0.1$.
>
> At this time, **how many cases will be required for this post-marketing surveillance** to achieve a detection power of $90\%$?
>   Select best answer from the following choices:
>
> > ① 114, ② 164, ③ 214, ④ 264, ⑤ 314
> >
> > **→ Ans2: ④ (264 cases)**

**References:**
 Quiz No.3 of the exam of the "2019's semi-first grade of Japan Statistical Society Certificate" is stored in the following URL. (Written in Japanese) That is an excerpt from only the part related to this quiz. [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_gmUFeHEqYn_QVyC4UnHWxY96jtL_qkA)

**P.S.**
P.S. I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions. I welcome any corrections and English review. (You can edit my question and description to improve them)

---

**Post-hoc notes:**
**【My answer to quiz 1】** : 
Rocco gave his answer to Quiz 1 on September 6th (JST). *Edit:As a result of discussion with Rocco, as for Question 1, both my results and Rocco's results agreed with the official answer.*  <s>But, as he says, is not consistent with the official answer.
Neither he nor I can find any mistakes in his answer so far.</s> 
I tried a different method than him:That is 
[Test of population ratio](http://www.aoni.waseda.jp/abek/document/chi-test.html)(Sorry, but linked document is written in English.)

We define the test-static Z as follows.

$$Z:= \frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)/N}}. \ \ (eq. P.H.N 1-01)$$

As the manner of [Test of population ratio](http://www.aoni.waseda.jp/abek/document/chi-test.html)(Sorry but written in Japanese), the Z of (eq. P.H.N 1-01) follows Normal standard distribution.

Substitute values for p and N, p=0.05, N=475, as a result,

$$Z = \frac{\hat{p}-0.05}{\sqrt{0.05(1-0.05)/475}}=100(\hat{p}-0.05) . \ \ (eq. P.H.N 1-02)$$

Here, $\hat{p} >0.0733$ therefore,

$$Z > 100(0.0733-0.05) = 2.33 \ \ (eq. P.H.N 1-03)$$

On the other hand, by using Excel Worksheet function, 
"=1-NORMDIST(2.33,0,1,TRUE)" , the result is "0.009903", therefore,

$$P (Z > 2.5) = 0.009903. \ \ (eq. P.H.N 1-04)$$

Therefore, the best answer among choices, ① is the closest.

**【My answer of Quiz 2,】** : (But it doesn't  much official answer.)
To  clear my head to investigate Quiz 2, I made a schematic illustration (See Fig.PFN2-1).

[image]
**Fig.PFN2-1**

Figure legends of Fig.PFN2-1 is as follows.

> - The sky-blue line (0) represents the “distribution of null
>     hypothesis.”
> - The orange line (1) represents the “distribution of
>     alternative hypothesis.”
> - μ0 represents the mean-value of (0).
> - μ1 represents the mean-value of (1).
> - a represents Upper α point of the distribution (1)
> - The area hatched dark-blue represents α.
> - The area hatched sky-blue represents β.
> - The area hatched orange represents(including dark-blue area) (1-β).

Using the above figure, I tried the calculation as follows.

First, according to the null hypothesis, the test static ${Z}_{0} $ in (eq.P.H.N2-01) follows a standard normal distribution. Where ${p}_{0} $ is the "Probability of the incidence of adverse events of the population under the ${H}_{0}$". From the question sentence, ${p}_{0}=0.05$.

$${Z}_{0}:= \frac{\hat{p}-{p}_{0}}{\sqrt{{p}_{0}(1-{p}_{0})/N}}. \ \ (eq. P.H.N 2-01)$$

Therefore, the average ${\mu}_{0}$ and the standard deviation $ {\sigma}_{0}$ of the distribution (0) are as follows.

$${\sigma}_{0}= \sqrt{{p}_{0}(1-{p}_{0})/N} =0.218/\sqrt{N} \ \ (eq. P.H.N 2-02)$$
$${\mu}_{0}= {p}_{0}{\sigma}_{0} =0.05\cdot 0.218/\sqrt{N}=0.0109/\sqrt{N} \ \ (eq. P.H.N 2-03)$$

Now, α = 0.025, so  by using the Excel worksheet function, the upper α point of the standard normal distribution, ${Z}_{\alpha}$ will be like the following formula (eq.P.H.N2-04)

${Z}_{\alpha}$ =1-NORMINV(0.025,0,1)= 2.96   (eq. P.H.N 2-04)

Therefore, the "a" in the figure is as following formula.

$$a={Z}_{\alpha}*{\sigma}_{0} + {\mu}_{0} ={Z}_{\alpha}{\sigma}_{0} + {p}_{0}{\sigma}_{0}  \ \ (eq. P.H.N 2-05)$$

Next, according to the altanative hypothesis, the test static ${Z}_{1}$ in (eq.P.H.N2-05) follows a standard normal distribution. Where $ {p} _ {1} $ is the "Probability of the incidence of adverse events of the population under the ${H}_{1}$". From the question sentence, ${p}_ {1}=0.1$.

$${Z}_{1}:= \frac{\hat{p}-{p}_{1}}{\sqrt{{p}_{1}(1-{p}_{1})/N}} \ \ (eq. P.H.N 2-06)$$

Therefore, the average ${\mu}_{1}$ and the standard deviation ${\sigma}_{1}$ of the distribution (1) are as follows.

$${\sigma}_{1}= \sqrt{{p}_{1}(1-{p}_{1})/N} = 0.3/ \sqrt{N} \ \ (eq. P.H.N 2-07)$$
$${\mu}_{1}= {p}_{1}{\sigma}_{1} =0.1\cdot 0.3/ \sqrt{N} =0.03/ \sqrt{N}  \ \ (eq. P.H.N 2-08)$$

Substituting $a$ into $\hat{p}$in formula.
$${Z}_{1,a} = \frac{{\sigma}_{0}({Z}_{\alpha} + {p}_{0})-{p}_{1}}{{\sigma}_{1}}
= \frac{{\sigma}_{0}}{{\sigma}_{1}}({Z}_{\alpha} + {p}_{0})-{p}_{1}/{\sigma}_{1}
 \ \ (eq. P.H.N 2-09)$$

Here,
$${\sigma}_{0}/{\sigma}_{1}= 0.218\sqrt{N} / 0.300\sqrt{N}  = 0.727\ \ (eq. P.H.N 2-10)$$

On the other hand, ${Z}_{1,a}$ is the upper 90% of the normal distribution from the problem statement. Therefore,

${Z}_{1,a}$=1-NORMINV(0.9,0,1)= -0.28155  (eq. P.H.N 2-13)

Therefore, 
$N$ =((1-NORMINV(0.9,0,1)+2.15)/0.17)^2 = 10.99087^2 = 120.7993     (eq. P.H.N 2-14)

**【My answer of Quiz 2-2】** : (It is consistent to official answer, added on 2020.04.11(JST))
Let $n$ be the number of cases, null hypothesis ($H_0$) be "p = 0.05", alternative hypothesis($H_1$) be "p=0.1". 
Under those settings, we conduct a one-sided test.
Under the $H_0$ and $H_1$, the estimated incidence ratio ($\hat{p}$) approximately follows $N(0.05,0.05\times 0.95/ n)$ and $N(0.1,0.1\times 0.9/n)$ respectivly.

Under this approximation, if the power is set to 90%, the critical point for rejection is expressed by the following eq P.H.N 3-01.
$$0.1- {Z}_{0.9}\sqrt{0.1\times 0.9 /n} \tag{P.H.N 3-01}$$

Also, under that normal approximation, if the significance level is set to 2.5% under this approximation, the rejection critical point is expressed by the following eq P.H.N 3-02.
$$0.05 - {Z}_{0.975}\sqrt{0.05\times 0.95 /n} \tag{2P.H.N 3-02}$$

Here, ${Z}_{0.975}$ and ${Z}_{0.9}$ respectively represent the lower 97.5 % point and lower 90 % point of the standard normal distribution;  ${Z}_{0.975}=1.96$, ${Z}_{0.9}=0.9$.

From the above, if the power is 90% and the significance level is 2.5%, the following eq3 shall be approximately satisfied.
$$0.1- {Z}_{0.9}\sqrt{0.1\times 0.9 /n}=0.05 - {Z}_{0.975}\sqrt{0.05\times 0.95 /n} \tag{P.H.N 3-03}$$

Solving the P.H.N 3-03 for n gives the following P.H.N 3-04.
$$n =
\frac{{(1.96\sqrt{0.05\times 0.95 /n}+
1.28\sqrt{0.1\times 0.9 /n})}^{2}}{{0.05^2}} = 263.2
 \tag{P.H.N 3-04}$$

Comment: ＠FFjet　Thank you for your editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried solving the first one, but I get the wrong result (*EDIT: NOW IT'S CORRECT*). I ended up using some cumbersome route, if anyone can point out what I did wrong I would be glad. I leave it here because maybe it can be useful to OP anyways!

Let's start from the first problem.

**Step 1:** **we write the probability $P(k|N,p)$**: "probability that we observe $k$ adverse events out of $N$ total events, given that the probability for an event to be adverse is $p$". This is an elementary result (I can provide details if you want):
\begin{align}P(k|N,p) = {N\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{N-k}\tag 1\end{align}

**Step 2:** Your problem hints at $N$ being "large enough" for $\hat p$ to be "approximately normally distributed". So let's start by **finding an approximation of $P(k|N,p)$ for large $N$**. We'll use Stirling's approximation: $\log N! \approx N\log N - N$ and get:
\begin{align}
P(k|N,p) =& {N\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{N-k}
\\ \quad\\ \approx &\exp\{N\log N - k\log k - (N-k)\log (N-k) + k \log p + (N-k)\log (1-p) \}
=\\
\quad\\=&\exp\left\{-N\left[\frac{k}{N}\log(\frac{k/N}{p}) + \frac{N-k}{N} \log (\frac{(N-k)/N }{1-p})\right]\right\}\\ \quad \\=& e^{-N \; D_{KL}(P_{\text{emp}}||\mathcal B(p))}
\tag 2\end{align}
where:

- $P_{\text{emp}}$ is the "empirical" distribution: $\{P(\text{adverse}) = \frac{k}{N}, P(\text{non adverse}) = \frac{N-k}{N}\}$
- $\mathcal B(p)$ is the Bernoulli distribution: $\{P(\text{adverse}) = p, P(\text{non adverse}) = 1-p\}$
- $D_{KL}(P_{\text{emp}}||\mathcal B(p))$ is the "Kullback-Leibler" distance between those two distributions. It is defined to be the expression in $[ \;]$ brackets you see just before

**Step 3:** Let's now **find what is our best estimator for $p$** given a set of $N$ observations comprising $k$ adverse events.
We can compute the probability $P(p|k,N)$ via Bayes rule:
\begin{align}P(p|k,N) = \frac{P(k|p,N)P(p|N)}{P(k|N)}\tag 3 \end{align}
We are interested in finding the value $\hat p$ maximizing this probability. We'll do it by computing the derivative of this expression and setting it to zero. We don't care about the denominator ${P(k|N)}$ since it does not depend on $p$. We also forget about $P(p|N)$ since, in lack of any prior information, it is uniform in $p$ (so it acts as a multiplicative constant). The only term remaining is $P(k|p,N)$, of which we have a $N>>1$ approximation from step 2! So we have:
\begin{align} P(p|k,N) \propto e^{-N \; D_{KL}(P_{\text{emp}}||\mathcal B(p))}\tag 4 \end{align}
If we compute its derivative with respect to $p$ and set it to $0$ we find (I omit the computation):
 \begin{align}\hat p = \frac{k}{N}\tag 5 \end{align}
**Step 4:** **we further approximate $P(k|p,N)$ making it Gaussian**. To do this, me must Taylor-expand this with respect to the variable $x=\frac{k}{N}$, around the point $x=p$. Terms of order $0$ and $1$ all cancel out, and we end out with (if you want, I will provide details of the computation):
\begin{align} P(k|p,N) \propto e^{-\frac{\left(\frac{k}{N}-p\right)^2}{2\left(\frac{p(1-p)}{N}\right)}}\tag 6 \end{align}
We can normalize this:
\begin{align} P\left(\frac{k}{N} = x\; \bigg|\; p,N\right) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \frac{p(1-p)}{N}}}e^{-\frac{\left(x-p\right)^2}{2\left(\frac{p(1-p)}{N}\right)}}\tag 7 \end{align}

*Notice: this can be seen as an instance of the Central Limit Theorem!*

**Step 5: we solve the problem**. Since we now have $\hat p = \frac{k}{N}$ and an expression for $P\left(\frac{k}{N} = x\; \bigg|\; p,N\right)$, we can see that the probability of $\hat p > 0.0733$, under the null hypothesis $p=0.05$ and with $N=475$, will be the integral:

\begin{align} P(\hat p > 0.0733) =& \int_{0.0733}^1 dx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \frac{0.05(1-0.05)}{475}}}e^{-\frac{\left(x-0.05\right)^2}{2\left(\frac{0.05(1-0.05)}{475}\right)}}
\\&=\frac{1}{0.01\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0.0733}^1 dx e^{-\frac{\left(x-0.05\right)^2}{2\left(0.0001\right)}}\tag 8 \end{align}

We can perform the change of variable: $z=\frac{x-0.05}{0.01\sqrt 2}$ to get:
\begin{align}P(\hat p > 0.0733)=& \int_{\frac{2.33}{\sqrt 2}}^{\frac{95}{\sqrt 2}} \frac{e^{-z^2}}{\sqrt \pi} dz= \frac{1}{2} \left[erf\left(\frac{95}{\sqrt 2}\right)-erf\left( \frac{2.33}{\sqrt 2} \right)\right] \\ \approx& \frac{1}{2}erfc\left(\frac{2.33}{\sqrt 2}\right)\approx 0.01\tag 9 \end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it answer for (Quiz 1)?

Comment: Yes, but it gives the wrong result! I cannot find the error :/

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote a wrong answer. The correct answer for quiz 1 is 0.01.　About half of your answer.

Comment: ＠Rocco　Dividing your answer by 2 is almost the same as official answer of Quiz 1. I forgot to translate the Quiz 1 as a one-sided test. This has already been fixed. Sorry, I haven't been able to trace all of your calculations, but if you were doing a two-sided test, wouldn't it match the official answer if you did a one-sided test?

Comment: ＠Rocco　If so, originally, this Quizzes were a matter of choosing the best one from the choices. So $| Official Answer - Your Answer/2 | = |0.001-0.0032/2| = 0.0006$ seems to be Neglect-able.

Comment: ＠Rocco I googled the “already approximated formula”. This seems to be called two-proportion z-test. This is probably equivalent to your solution. I will try to solve quiz 1 using this formula.

https://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx

Comment: ＠Rocco I want to number all of your formulas to make discussion easier. Can I do it?

Comment: I added my answer to [My answer to quiz 1]. I want to compare it with your answer. If there is no objection, I would like to write a formula number in your article around 18:00 on September 9th in Japan Standard Time. Is there a problem?

Comment: I must admit I'm not accustomed to elementary statistics (I only know things I needed for my physics work) so I'm not sure about the "1-sided" test thing. I would say my test is already "1-sided" since in the first formula of "Step 5" I perform the integral only on one of the tails of the Gaussian. Still, I'm not sure.
By the way: be careful about your [proposed solution] because if you get 0.0621 at the end, that is very much closer to ③ than ① !

Comment: Thank you for numbering and re-organizing your formula. And thank you for your comment.■
>if you get 0.0621 .. is very much closer to ③ than ① ! ■
Oops! I simply rounded off the third decimal place of 0.99379 (1-0.99379), but it seems that it was my jumping to conclusions. I will add a note to my question about this mistake. Sorry.■
> I perform the integral only on one of the tails of the Gaussian. 
■Certainly, it seems to me too that the integration interval in equation (8) is for the one-sided test.

Comment: I have the following questions.■
For eq(3):■
Am I right if:■
$P(p|k,N)$  is the probability of "the probability of adverse events occur in the population is p " when k adverse events occur from $N$,■　
$P(k|N)$ is the probability that k people with adverse events occurred among $N$ people. ■

For eq(5): Is it the conclusion of Step 3 ? Is this an extreme point when differentiating by $\textbf{p}$ eq(4)?

Comment: For eq(6): Details of the computation, please. ■
For eq(7): Is this the eq(7) equivalent to the statment that "my (eq.P.H.N1-01)  follows a normal distribution?"■

I'd like to pending the question about equations after (7) this expression for this moment.

Comment: For eq. 3:

$P(p|k,N)=$  "The  probability that the probability of adverse events is p, given that we observed k adverse events in N events";
$P(k|N)=$ "The probability of observing k adverse events in N events, given that we know nothing about how much is the probability p of a single adverse event". This is really not important since we want to differentiate in p to find $\hat p$ later so this term acts as a multiplicative constant. A good reference for basic bayesian parameter inference is the book "Probability Theory: The Logic Of Science" by E.T Jaynes

Comment: OK I see the issue: When dealing with tails of gaussians, you should never approximate like you do when you write 0.075 instead of 0.0733. It seems like a minor difference but gaussian tails fall very fast and even this tiny 0.0066 gained in your approximation can make a huge difference. If you use the correct value, you'll see that your cumulative distribution "1-NORMDIST(2.33,0,1,TRUE)" gives the result 0.0099, that you can roud off to 0.01. (by the way, I noticed you forgot to write a 0 in 0.00621!). I also corrected an error in my last equation (pi instead of 2). Now it's ok! :)

Comment: Congratulations!! Quiz 1 seems to have been completely solved.
That's how big the difference is! ! I'll fix my answer by  using  "1-NORMDIST(2.33,0,1,TRUE)" .

Comment: For eq. 3:However, you derive eq 5 by differentiating this formula by p. How do you justify treating P (p, N) as a constant?

Comment: Hehe, that's a huge thing you're asking :) P(p|N) is a "prior" in Bayesian inference. It encodes "what you know of 'p' before making any observations". A common and effective recipe is to set it to be constant when you don't have any prior information about the parameter you're estimating. For detailed discussion, I strongly recommend the book cited before. What often happens is that Bayesian statistics reduces to classical (Fisher-) statistics when you take *constant* prior distributions. It's too wide a topic to be discussed here though! :) (can I move this whole discussion to the chat?)

Comment: OK, this field is too narrow to write such a huge topic.
[Is this the book you said? ](https://www.amazon.co.jp/Probability-Theory-Science-T-Jaynes/dp/0521592712/)
It seems little expensive compering with my pocket money residue this month.
  But it seems good. I'll definitely buy it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98503/discussion-between-rocco-and-blue-various).

Comment: I posted my idea for Quiz2.
But it doesn't seem to much official answer.I want to apologize for being off for a while.

Comment: Quiz 2  has been solved. Please find【My answer of Quiz 2-2】. Thank you!!