# How many cases are needed to prove safety?

Tags: probability, statistics

The following Quizzes are the rough translation (with minor modification) of Quizzes **No.03-2-(1)** and **No.03-2-(2)** of the exam of the "2019's semi-first grade of Japan Statistical Society Certificate (JSSC)" (See the column named **【Quizzes and Official Answers】** and ref.(1)). The correct answers by the JSSC  are also described under each Quiz(See the column named **【Quizzes and Official Answers】** and ref.(1)). For Quizzes 3- 1, see the following page.
[How many cases are needed to get enough power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345934/how-many-cases-are-needed-to-get-enough-power)

> **【My question】**:
>   How can I reach the correct answer?

---

> **【Quizzes and Official Answers】**
>   In the area of pharmaceuticals, adverse events detected during clinical trials are appropriately monitored in post-marketing surveillance.
>
> - Let $N$ be sample size of the clinical trial.
> - Let $p$ be the probability of the incidence of adverse events occurrence of the population ($0\le p \le 1$).Hereinafter, the $p$ is also reffed to as "probability of occurrence"
>
> **(Quiz1)** Eight cases were independently examined for the events with a probability of occurrence of $p=0.05$. Then, **what is the probability that at least one this adverse event will be observed ?** Select best answer from the following choices.
>
> > ① 0.05, ② 0.24, ③ 0.34, ④ 0.40, ⑤ 0.66
> >     **→Ans. ③ ($0.34$).**
>
> **(Quiz2)**
>   An adverse event was not observed in the clinical trial ($N = 475$). 
>   We are planning  a post-marketing surveillance to judge whether this adverse event is safe or not. This adverse event is **considered safe from a safety viewpoint if $p<0.01$**.
>
> The definition of $n$ is as follow.
>
> > For the advertise event, whose probability of occurrence, $p$ is $0.01$,
> >      **let $n$ be simple size such that, "the chance of observing at least one this adverse event during this post-marketing surveillance" is $95$ %**.
>
> Then, even if above-mentioned $n$ cases are observed independently, if no adverse event is observed, then, we judged that $p<0.01$. And, therefore, it is safe.
>
> At this time , **how many $n$ are necessary for post-marketing surveillance to prove safety ?**
>   Select best answer from the following choices.
>
> > ① 1,000, ② 1,500, ③ 2,000, ④ 2,500, ⑤ 3,000
> >     **→Ans. ③ ($n=3000$ cases).**

**References:**
Quizzes  No.3 of the exam of the "2019's semi-first grade of Japan Statistical Society Certificate" is stored in the following URL. (Written in Japanese) That is an excerpt from only the part related to this quiz. [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_gmUFeHEqYn_QVyC4UnHWxY96jtL_qkA)

**P.S.**
P.S. I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions. I welcome any corrections and English review. (You can edit my question and description to improve them)

Comment: Have you tried using binomial probability for your first question?

Comment: @Toby Mak Thank you for your hint. You mean "(Answer of Quiz 1) = 1-(1-0.05)^8 " Thank you very much.  It would be helpful if you provide comment or answer the following question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345934/how-many-cases-are-needed-to-get-enough-power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The probability of an adverse event occurring is 0.05, so the probability that a case does not have an adverse event is $1 - 0.05 = 0.95$. Since $8$ cases were examined, with each case being an independent event, the probability that none of the cases will have an adverse event is $0.95^8 = 0.6634$. From this, the probability that at least one adverse event will occur is 1 minus the probability that none occur. So, $1-0.6634 = 0.3366$.
2. For the second problem, the probability that an adverse event is observed in a case is 0.001, so the probability that no adverse event is observed is $1 - 0.001 = 0.999$. The definition of $n$ states the probability that at least one adverse event occurring must be 0.95. So the probability that none occurring would have to be $1-0.95 = 0.05$. So, we have to find how many independent cases must occur so that the probability of no adverse affects being seen is $0.05$. This is denoted by $0.999^x = 0.05$. This is equivalent to $\log _{0.999} 0.05  = \frac{\ln 0.05}{\ln 0.999} = 2994$

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to you, I understood the way to answer. The original problem was to choose the most appropriate one of the options. Therefore, there seems to be a little difference from the official answer. I will revise the question sentence.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide comment or answer the following questions. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345934/how-many-cases-are-needed-to-get-enough-power